# Error when calculate average temperature on hbase

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

i want calculate  average temperature on table test(info:date,info:temp) in hbase and put the result into table result(info:date,info:avg).
However when running the program it gave me an error.

the code is:

```
public static class mapper1 extends TableMapper<Text,FloatWritable>
    {   
        public static final byte[] Info = "info".getBytes();
        public static final byte[] Date = "date".getBytes();
        public static final byte[] Temp = "temp".getBytes();
        private static Text key=new Text();


        public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row,Result value,Context context)  
   throws IOException
             {         
            String k1 = new String(value.getValue(Info, Date));
            key.set(k1);
            byte[] val=value.getValue(Info,Temp);
        try
            {
                context.write(key,new 
   FloatWritable(Float.parseFloat(Bytes.toString(val))));
            }

         catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                throw new IOException(e);
            }
             }}
```

//**********************************************************************************************************************

```
    public static class reducer1 extends TableReducer<Text,Result,Text>
        {
        public static final byte[] info = "info".getBytes();
        public static final byte[] date = "date".getBytes(); 
        byte[] avg ;


     public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<FloatWritable>values, Context context)   
throws IOException, InterruptedException
            {
                float sum=0;
                int count=0;
                float average=0;
                for(FloatWritable val:values)
                {
                    sum+=val.get();
                    count++;
                }
                average=(sum/count);

                Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(key.toString()));
                put.add(info, date, Bytes.toBytes(average));

                System.out.println("For\t"+count+"\t average is:"+average);

               context.write(key,put);
            }
        }
```

//***********************************************************************************************************************

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws 
 IOException,ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException, NullPointerException
        {
            Configuration config=HBaseConfiguration.create();
            config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost");
            HTable table1 = new HTable(config, "test");
            HTable table2 = new HTable(config, "result");

            Job job=new Job(config,"AVG");
            Scan scan=new Scan();
            scan.addFamily("info".getBytes());
            scan.setFilter(new FirstKeyOnlyFilter());

            TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
                    "test",        
                    scan,              
                    mapper1.class,     
                    Text.class,         
                    FloatWritable.class,  
                    job);
            TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(
                    "result",        
                    reducer1.class,    
                    job);
                job.setNumReduceTasks(1); 

                boolean b = job.waitForCompletion(true);
                if (!b) {
                    throw new IOException("error with job!");
                }
                 }
  }
```

The error message is:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.reverseDns(DNS.java:92)
     at  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.reverseDNS(TableInputFormatBase.java:223)
    at 
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:452)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:469)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1215)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at 
     org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1236)
    at TempVar.AVG.main(AVG.java:126)
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the computer name returned by zookeeper where hbase should be is not recognized 
either configure the DNS correctly or if you don't use that add the mapping form names to ip addresses in the /etc/hosts file